# How to make TableView Header Static/ unScrollable

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I am working on Table View. I have implemented Header at the top of TableView. Its scrolling when i scroll TableView. Any Solution to make the Header Static.

Comment: As you are saying it is static so add just one view above table view and design it as per your design.

Comment: see this : https://medium.com/@jeremysh/creating-a-sticky-header-for-a-uitableview-40af71653b55

Comment: `UITableView` also supports *section* headers which stick to the top of the screen only while that section is visible in the scroll view. Perhaps that's what you want?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer to expand the visibility of your question. Check how to do it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/469186

Answer (score 2):

If you want a static header, it means that it should not be a header. The behaviour of a header is to scroll with the `UITableView`.

You can replace it with an `UIView` placed above your `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the UITableView.headerView (UIView?), this is a view placed at the top end of the whole tableView and not per section as the sectionHeaderView.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add UIView On top of UITableView.

Like this :

[image]

And result will be:

[image]